# How To use Fingerprint Sensor Manager in DISPLAY built devices for example VIVO V15 and Oneplus6T etc

Tags: java, android

i want to authenticate the user with Fingerprint Sensor its working fine but  in some devices fingerprint is built on DISPLAY  for example VIVO V15 and Oneplus6T etc and on that devices its not working.